# normalize data in pig script

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following dataset :

```
1,11,ab;cd;200

2,22,pq;rs
```

I want this in output :

```
1,11,ab

1,11,cd

1,11,200

2,22,pq

2,22,rs
```

How can it be done in Pig without using any udf?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
A = load '....' using PigStorage(',') as (x,y,data : chararray);
SPLT = foreach A generate x, y, FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(data,';'));
X_tmp = foreach SPLT generate $0 as x, $1 as y, FLATTEN(TOBAG($2..$20)) as term; -- pivots the row
X = filter X_tmp by term is not null; -- this removes the extra bag rows when title was split in less than 20 terms
```

The assumption is that you will not have more than 20 elements in the data string. If you have more, than increase it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    A = load 'data' using PigStorage(',') as (x,y,data:chararray);
    SPLT = foreach A generate x, y, FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(data,';',3)) as (a,b,c);
    grp = group SPLT by (x,y);
    res = foreach grp generate group, FLATTEN(SPLT);
    out = foreach res generate FLATTEN(group), FLATTEN(TOBAG(SPLT::a, SPLT::b, strong textSPLT::c)) as val;
    dump out;
```